# How to test chrome app in chrome book

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, kiosk, chromebook

Could someone let me know how can a chrome app (without publishing ) is tested in Google chromebook so as to check its basic functionalities?

Answer (score 2):

You can test it in chrome in the same way as you test a chrome extension, as [described here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en):

> 1. Open Chrome and go to Chrome menu > Tools > Extensions.
> 2. Click Developer mode > Load unpacked extensions...
> 3. Browse to and Select the folder where your manifest.json file is and logo.
>      If your file doesn't immediately load, check to make sure the JSON code is formatted correctly with the JSON Validator.
> 4. Open a new tab in Chrome to see if your app loads and functions correctly. If not, tweak it and test it until it's working correctly in your browser.